OpenAI Chat Completions API for in context learning
The change from Completions API to Chat Completions API has confused on how I should structure my input to the model. Could someone teach me how I can convert the input to a format compatible with the Chat Completions API ?
prompt = """
You are a smart assistant that anticipates actions based on input sequences. The person performing the actions is right-handed. You can only choose actions that you see from the examples. Each action is encapsulated within a square bracket such as ['Pick', 'cucumber_attachment'] or ['Cut cucumber_attachment with knife_black'].
Complete the following actions in any valid order:
['RollOut dough']
['Open milk_small']
['Pour milk_small into mixing_bowl_green']
['Pour flour from cup_small into mixing_bowl_green'] or ['Scoop flour from cup_small into mixing_bowl_green']
['Scoop mixed contents from mixing_bowl_green into cup_large']
['End']

Here are some examples:

Sequence = [['Pick', 'milk_small'], ['Open milk_small'], ['Place', 'milk_small_lid'], ['Pick', 'mixing_bowl_green'], ['Pour milk_small into mixing_bowl_green'], ['Place', 'mixing_bowl_green'], ['Place', 'milk_small'], ['Pick', 'tablespoon'], ['Pick', 'cup_small'], ['Scoop flour from cup_small into mixing_bowl_green'], ['Place', 'tablespoon'], ['Place', 'cup_small'], ['Pick', 'egg_whisk'], ['Pick', 'cup_large'], ['Place', 'cup_large'], ['Pick', 'mixing_bowl_green'], ['Stir contents of mixing_bowl_green'], ['Place', 'egg_whisk'], ['Pick', 'ladle'], ['Scoop mixed contents from mixing_bowl_green into cup_large'], ['Place', 'ladle'], ['Place', 'mixing_bowl_green'], ['Pick', 'rolling_pin'], ['RollOut dough'], ['Place', 'rolling_pin'], ['End']]
Sequence = [['Pick', 'rolling_pin'], ['RollOut dough'], ['Place', 'rolling_pin'], ['Pick', 'tablespoon'], ['Pick', 'cup_small'], ['Scoop flour from cup_small into mixing_bowl_green'], ['Place', 'tablespoon'], ['Place', 'cup_small'], ['Pick', 'milk_small'], ['Open milk_small'], ['Pour milk_small into mixing_bowl_green'], ['Close milk_small_lid'], ['Pick', 'milk_small'], ['Place', 'milk_small'], ['Pick', 'egg_whisk'], ['Stir contents of mixing_bowl_green'], ['Place', 'egg_whisk'], ['Pick', 'ladle'], ['Pick', 'mixing_bowl_green'], ['Place', 'mixing_bowl_green'], ['Pick', 'cup_large'], ['Place', 'cup_large'], ['Scoop mixed contents from mixing_bowl_green into cup_large'], ['Place', 'ladle'], ['End']]

Now, anticipate the actions for the following input:
Input = [['Pick', 'milk_small']]
"""


When you move from Completions to Chat Completions, it is not just a case of changing the style of your prompt. Here is the simplest example of what the code might look like in Python:
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI()

response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": "You are a helpful assistant"
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Test"
        }
    ],
    temperature=0.5,
    max_tokens=200,
)
print(response.choices[0].message.content)

In your case you could clarify the task in the system content, and then ask the question in the user content. But you can also use 'role':'assistant' to give examples of what output you would like to see. Take a look here. And there is useful stuff here on prompt engineering

Was this any help?
